# Show that $K(X)$ is not a field for $X = Z(xy)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = Z(xy) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$. I want to show that the rational fuctions  on $X$ defined as 
$ K(X) := \{(U,f) : U ⊂ X \text{ is open and dense and } f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)\}/ \sim$, where $(U,f) \sim (V,g)$ if and only if there is an open and dense $W \subset U \cap V$ such that f = g on W is not a field.

I know that this is only the case, because the variety is reducible. So I am trying use this to show that there is some $(U,f)$ that does not have an inverse. I guess I should search around $(0,0)$ and take some function like $x$ (projection to the $x$-coordinate), but I am a little stuck with how to show that there is no inverse to such a pair. Is this intuition true? How do I show something like this?

Comment: Your approach is good - to show that the pair is not invertible, you might show the stronger statement that it's a zero divisor.

Comment: Thank you I get the idea now!